# Slide transition with API 10

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to make a screen slide to switch between two `Activities` (I'm not looking for a swipe effect, just the slide transition that is available for `viewPagers`).

Any suggestions or links on how this can be done with the API 10?

Comment: At least make an attempt at it first, showing us what you've tried or attempted and what has or hasn't worked...

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
the problem is that it cant be done with the api10.

Comment: What specifically cannot be done on api 10?  A viewpager in its most basic form is available in the support library and is available to API levels much below 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fully working example.

Preview what it looks like here: [Preview](http://i.imgur.com/iWRzhyR.gif)

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

`fragment_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

</ScrollView>
```

My only class

```
public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_viewpager);
        MyPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new FragmentExample();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

    public static class FragmentExample extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null, false);
        }
    }
}
```

And just for good measure, here is my manifest, note that the minimum sdk supported is **4**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.screenslidingpager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.screenslidingpager.ActivityMain"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The only problem I can see with my code is that activity_main.xml in which I didn't proeprly close the xml tag... Updated the snippet